# I just trying to run my first servlet but following errors I face

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

**HTTP Status:** 500 – Internal Server Error.
**Type:** Exception Report.
**Message:** Error instantiating servlet class [com.demo.AddServlet]
**Description:** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
**Exception:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.demo.AddServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


Root Cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.AddServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

AddServlet.java file code

```
    package com.demo;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    @WebServlet("/AddDemo")
    public class AddDemo extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
           
        public AddDemo() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        }


        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doGet(request, response);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Root Cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.AddServlet` That is the only relevant line in that stack trace. You've misconfigured your build or your tomcat. You didn't include sufficient details for a more thorough answer. I suggest you follow a tomcat tutorial.

Comment: You posted a Servlet  named  AddDemo but the code is looking for a Servlet named AddServlet.    What code  threw the exception?